# How do I retrieve the right timestamp from a MySQL database in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, database, timestamp

I'm storing measurements in a MySQL database.
The measurements contain a timestamp field which stores timestamps in the following format:

**2015-10-10 10:10:10.11** (so with two digits of milliseconds)

In my Java code I retrieve this value with:

**resultSet.getTimestamp(id)**

When I print this value it gives me:

**2015-10-10 11:11:11.000000011**

So I'm trying to figure out WHY it behaves like this and HOW I should solve this issue so I get the right value?

EDIT:

The values show correctly inside the database itself when using **select * from measurement**

My guess it should be somewhere in the way it is retrieved by Java / JDBC.
Both getTimestamp and getString give me the same result.

EDIT 2:

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from measurement");

Measurement m;

while(resultSet.next()) {
    m = new Measurement(
        resultSet.getString(1), 
        resultSet.getString(2), 
        resultSet.getDouble(4), 
        resultSet.getTimestamp(3));
    System.out.println(m);
}
```

Comment: can you please add more code, i can bet you store timestamp in a long or a double in some moment, then you lose precision....

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Tunaki I'm using MySQL 5.6.26 as I require at least 5.6.4 to store fractional seconds.

Comment: @Jordi Castilla I'm not storing the data by code yet, I've inserted it manually through PHPmyAdmin

Comment: as per your last comment: *You are probable right as getTimestamp().getNano() return the numbers I'm looking for. So somehow Java takes the fractional part and turns them into nanoseconds.*, please paste your java code that retrieves and converts from sql timestamp to java Date....

Comment: @Jordi Castilla added the code to original message

Comment: Try retrieving it as a String with resultSet.getString(3)... does it look the same?

Comment: If the code is using java Date then also the time-zone has to be taken in account. the timestamp didn't have the time-zone information, I guess, but Date has it. there is a possible information loss by converting from java Date to timestamp.

Comment: @Constatin Yes it does look the same.

Comment: @Andreas I just looked at the implementation of the getTimestamp() in the connector code. It looks like it parses the numbers after the '.' as nano's:

    if (numDigits < 9) {
    int factor = (int) (Math.pow(10, 9 - numDigits));
    nanos = nanos * factor;
    }

Answer (score 1):

I've never been a fan of how MySQL's JDBC driver deals with the TIMESTAMP type. I'd use:

```
select ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(col1)*1000) FROM measurement
```

And then read it with

```
java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date(resultSet.getLong(1));
```

Comment: This looks indeed like a solid workaround for my problem.
But then I could also just go and store the UNIX_TIMESTAMP I guess...

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into the implementation. Even though it's a bit over my head I found out some 'interesting' information.

The implementation of `com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getTimestamp()` has some clues:

```
int year = 0;
int month = 0;
int day = 0;
int hour = 0;
int minutes = 0;
int seconds = 0;
int nanos = 0; <<< CLUE
```

and

```
if (numDigits < 9) {
    int factor = (int) (Math.pow(10, 9 - numDigits));
    nanos = nanos * factor;
}
```

and

```
TimeUtil.fastTimestampCreate(tz, year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds, nanos);
```

So it seems to parse everything after the '.' as nanoseconds ending up with leading zeroes. so `.11` becomes `.000000011.`

So I think this explains the WHY it is happening...

The HOW to fix this could be in many ways, some being:

1. Getting the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` as user5449350's answer.
2. Storing `UNIX_TIMESTAMPS` instead of `TIMESTAMP` / `DATETIME`
3. Correct the faulty Date object and correct it using `Calendar`

   ```
   Date t = resultSet.getTimestamp(3);
   Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   c.setTime(t);
   c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, ((Timestamp)t).getNanos());
   t = c.getTime();
   ```